# Pycharm can't exit smoothly after run or debug

Tags: pycharm

I just upgrade Pycharm to 2017.3 on OSX and I find that some strange on console

I just run a very simple demo on it. Like this 
[image]

I don't why it can't stop like some debugging

and after I run debug a.py it get the same problem
[image]

It's very **strange** .**To stop it ,you must click the stop button**, but this situation didn't happen when using old version Pycharm .

**After click stop buttom**

on **run** mode
[image]

on **debug** mode
[image]

Pycharm console can't exit smoothly
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix solution:

Change your *Run/Debug configuration* for your `a.py` file:

```
Run | Edit Configurations...
```

then in the left pane select your `a.py` file (in spite it is dimmed), and then
 uncheck the *Show command line aftewards* option:

[image]